# In NestJs, commons folder is added to dist folder and not accessed from src

Tags: node.js, nestjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmrBV.png)
I am working on a project that uses NestJs. I noticed that when I am running `npm run start` it works fine, but if I build it first, `npm run build` then it adds commons folder in the dist folder.
Can anyone tell me where I could be wrong?

I was expecting it to access the email templates from the path 'dist/src/commons', but when I run it in `npm run start:prod` it is unable to access it. And in the dist folder it creates commons folder along with src.

Comment: the question is unclear. if you have written something like ../dist/commons in your ts file, it's going to be compiled into javascript in the dist folder and run it, but can't find another dist folder there, you shouldn't be doing it like that. This is probably the case, but you have asked very unclearly and we haven't seen any code